# MS Access Copy image from clipboard

Tags: image, ms-access, vba, clipboard

I found a problem and don't know how solve it.

I have a picture on clipboard, and I need create a BMP file with clipboard value.

I found this code:

```
﻿Dim clip As Object
Set clip = CreateObject("clipbrd.clipboard")
SavePicture clip.getdata, "C:\image.bmp"
Set clip = Nothing
```

But in the line: Set clip = CreateObject("clipbrd.clipboard")    I receive error: Error 426 Active x cannot create the object

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to an old VB6 activeX that is not present on your system (and most of any actual systems).

Someone rewrote a syntax-compatible ActiveX (as a third party *clipboard.dll* to be installed on your system). You probably missed it where you've found this sample code.

See [this article](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?585616-clipboard-activex-for-vba-vbs-etc) and read it with attention.

*Disclaimer: I am not involved in this component in any way, as it is a third party component, you use it at your own risk. See its author and/or source code for details.*